# Can headers always be combined?

Tags: http, http-headers, language-lawyer

If I have two headers with the same name (and assuming that this makes sense and is valid)

```
Some-Header: foo
Some-Header: bar
```

can they always be combined?

```
Some-Header: foo,bar
```

I am looking for guarantees (or lack thereof) made by the HTTP RFCs. (If the standards differ from practice, I'd be interested in hearing that too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, yes, see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#field.order.

(and note the exception for Set-Cookie)